# Highcharts checkboxes multiply when window resize event fires

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I have an app which contains checkbox at the bottom of the chart (by the legend item).

When I resize the app window, event listener (which logs 'resize' events) changes the chart width accordingly and a new checkbox appears on the chart.

A new checkbox also appears as well when the chart theme is changed.

This makes me believe that whenever Highcharts are re-rendered (I use React), a new checkbox is created.

Initially, there is only one checkbox:

[image]

After single resize of the page:

[image]

After multiple resizes:

[image]

Also, there is always one checkbox at the top right corner of the chart (appears after the first resize):

[image]

The checkBox is added to the chart only once, at the componendDidMount() cycle. It is added to a single series using this option:

`showCheckbox: true`

The first and the only time the function that generates charts and sets this option is called in the main components cycle componentDidMount:

Main Container

```
import Charts from './Charts';
import * as highcharts from 'highcharts';

class MainComponent exteds React.Component<Props, State> {

    public async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            // Here the charts are generated
            const initialOpts = Charts.generateCharts(); 

            const min = 1000;
            const max = 5000;
            highcharts.charts.map(chart => {
                chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max, undefined, false)
            });
        } catch { ... }
        this.chartDimensionsHandler();
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.chartDimensionsHandler);
    }

    private chartDimensionsHandler() {
        const chartHeight: number = ZoomService.getChartHeight();
        this.setState({ chartHeight }); 
        // When the state is set, component re-renders and causes the issue
    }
    /* 
    Theme is passed as props to the main component thus whenever theme changes, 
    new props arrive and component along with higcharts is also 
    re-rendered what causes a new checkbox to appear on top right of the chart
    */
}
```

Charts class

```
export class ChartService {
    public generateCharts() {
        return this.charts.map((char) => this.generateDataChart(chart));
    }



    private generateDataChart(chart: Chart): Options {
        const { slices } = chart;
        const xValues = slices.map(slice =>
          Number(slice[chart.xAxis.name].value)
        );
        const xAxis = this.generateXAxisOptions(chart);
        const yAxis = [ ... ];

        const options = { xAxis, yAxis };

        // Create line series
        try {
          const lineSeries = this.constructDataSeries(chart, xValues);

          // Create events series
          const eventsCharts = this.charts.filter(
            x => x.type === 'events'
          );
          const eventsSeries = eventsCharts.map((evChart: Chart) => {
            // Here I call a function which sets 'showCheckbox' to true
            const allEvents = this.createEventSeries(evChart!)[0];
            allEvents.yAxis = 1;
            return allEvents;
          });

          const otherSeries = ...; // Irrelevant code

          // Add all series
          const series = [...otherSeries, ...eventsSeries];
          return Object.assign(options, { series });
        } catch (e) {
          return Object.assign(
            options,
            { series: [] },
            {
              lang: {
                noData: `Fail.`
              }
            }
          );
        }
      }

  private constructEventSeries(chart) {
    const { slices, yAxis, xAxis } = chart;
    const xValues = slices.map(slice =>
      Number(slice[xAxis.name].value)
    );

    return yAxis.map((item) => ({
      name: item.label,
      type: 'line',
      data: this.convertEventData(slices, xValues),
      lineWidth: 0,
      showCheckbox: true, // THE PLACE WHERE I SET showCheckbox to true
      marker: {
        enabled: true,
        radius: 10,
        symbol : 'circle'
      },
      meta: {
        type: 'events'
      }
    }));
  }

}
```

Does anyone have an idea why a new checkbox is added to the chart every single render of it (no matter if the chart is resized or not)?

Comment: Show the relevant code.

Comment: any warning on console? are you using map? and in general you should provide your code or a sandbox that re-creates the same problem

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Edited the post, added the code.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi The code in the app is very destructurized, it would be difficult to move everything into a sandbox, sorry. I attached the code to this post

Comment: so I am pretty sure that the problem is from indexing during mapping, on each re-render the dom element related to the checkbox gets replicated. don't you get any warning in the console about the `key`? can check the code more deeply ASA get to my laptop

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi No warnings at all. I stopped the component from re-rendering by removing 'setState' call. Now, the component does not re-render, only the resize event fires. Seems like this window event is what causes the issue. Sadly, I have no idea why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that whenever `resize` event is logged, Highcharts automatically calls `chart.reflow()` function which caused the checkmarks to be multiplied. Component setState function made the situation even worse.

By changing the function which is called by the event from setting component's state into setting chart's dimensions directly with higcharts function `chart.setSize(width, height, animation: boolean)`.

Then in the CSS I set the display of the second checkbox to none by using nth child property (because `resize` event always creates the second checkbox, there is no way to shut it (probably a bug from highcharts)).

This was my solution.